# CountIF cells related to a date range (month)

Tags: google-sheets

I have a real estate company and have a spreadsheet that tabulates all the data on our closed deals. One column is the date that the property closed. I am trying to figure out a formula that automatically counts the cells(closed deals) from the closed date column that will then put that number in a summary column of deals closed each month.

Thinking `COUNTIF(d1:d24,>01/01/22,<01/30/22)` for the month of January.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data. Enter textual descriptions in cells to tell what you want in the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using countif, try countifs (with the s at the end):

```
=COUNTIFS(D1:D24,">=01/01/2022",D1:D24,"<=30/01/2022")
```

If it doesn't work, show (share or make a similar sample) your spreadsheet. Visualizing it makes it easier to help...

Answer (score 0):

Just to show that Google Sheets often provides more than one way of getting an outcome, try this `query`.

`=query({D2:D24},"select count(Col1) where Col1 >= date '2022-01-01' and Col1 <= date '2022-01-30' label Count(Col1) ''")`

---

**SAMPLE**

[image: sample]

Answer (score 0):

Rather than hardcoding dates into formula, use a dynamic formula and reference date cells.

**Query**

- `=query(A1:D8,"select count(D) where D is not null and D >= date '"&TEXT(G8,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and D <= date '"&TEXT(G9,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'  label count(D) ''")`

**Countifs**

- `=countifs($D$2:$D,">="&$G$3,$D$2:$D,"<="&$G$4)`

---

[image: snapshot]